# Set active theme via URL

Tags: plugins, themes

I have a new WP site with a couple of candidate themes, and would like the end user to be able to "browse" my themes. For that, I would like to use the [Theme Switcher](https://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-switcher/) plugin By Ryan Boren, or something better if available, because something led me to believe it would allow me to specify a theme to be activated via the URL. I cannot find any docs on how to configure it for URL parsing though.

All I can find is a Theme Switcher sidebar widget, which causes trouble if the end user (or even me) uses that widget to switch to a theme with no sidebar.

I don't want that as an end feature either. I want to present the client with a list of URLs, each for the same site but with a different theme parameter.

**PS:** I have found a few solutions that select a template for a post via the post's URL, but I'm not certain whether a post type template would be the same as a full on, installed, theme.

Comment: have you checked how the preview theme works?

Comment: @DavidLee No, it didn't at first occur to me to do that. In fact, I'm busy looking at it now. Thanks.

Comment: The shareable preview link, with the `customize_changeset_uuid` GET parameter, from the Customizer, came first to mind here, but unfortunately it doesn't support theme switching, see e.g. tickets [#42411](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42411) and  [#42126](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42126)

Answer (score 6):

I created simple class which will do exactly what you want. To switch theme you must add theme GET parameter to your site url with name of the theme. http://example.com/?theme=twentyfifteen

Selected theme will also be stored in cookie so next time the user enters the site he will have earlier selected theme.

```
class WPSE_287356_Theme_Switcher {

    /**
     * Theme which we want to activate
     */
    private $theme;

    /**
     * Cookie name
     */
    private $cookie;

    /**
     * GET parameter name
     */
    private $get;

    /**
     * Switched
     */
    private $switched;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {

        /**
         * Get default theme
         */
        $this->theme = get_option('template');

        /**
         * Define cookie name
         */
        $this->cookie = 'theme';

        /**
         * Define get parameter name
         */
        $this->get = 'theme';

        /**
         * Define if theme is already switched
         */
        $this->switched = false;

        $this->handle_url();
        $this->switch_theme();

        /**
         * Define plugin related hooks
         */
        $this->define_hooks();
    }

    /**
     * Get theme
     */
    public function get_theme() {

        return $this->theme;
    }

    /**
     * Handle for theme change
     *
     * When the user clicks special link with theme name we will
     * store this theme name in user cookies and 
     */
    public function handle_url() {

        if( isset( $_GET[$this->get] ) && !empty( $_GET[$this->get] ) ) {

            $theme = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $this->get, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

            // This part require some additional checking e.g if theme exits or is allowed.

            $this->theme = $theme;
            $this->switched = true;

            // Store theme in cookie to remember choice
            setcookie( $this->cookie, $theme, time() + ( 365 * DAY_IN_SECONDS ), COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Switch theme
     *
     * Check if user has cookie with theme name and eventualy switch theme
     */
    public function switch_theme() {

        if( isset( $_COOKIE[ $this->cookie ] ) && !$this->switched ) {

            $theme = filter_input( INPUT_COOKIE, $this->cookie, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

            // This part require some additional checking e.g if theme exits or is allowed.

            $this->theme = $theme;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Define plugin related hooks
     */
    private function define_hooks() {

        /**
         * This filters will replace theme name across all WordPress
         */
        add_filter( 'template', array( $this, 'get_theme' ) );
        add_filter( 'stylesheet', array( $this, 'get_theme' ) );
    }
}

new WPSE_287356_Theme_Switcher();
```

Comment: I see the filters are set in the ctor, but where do I place this class and how do I trigger it's instantiation, in this case?

Comment: You can place it in your plugin or theme main file depending what you are doing. This script is working on each request, there is no need for installation.

Comment: It will have to be a plugin, because the whole objective is to change themes. If I put the code in any theme, I'll have to put it in all available themes.

Comment: So you have to make a plug-in.

Comment: I awarded the bounty because of your effort, and because it looks like it will  work, but I will accept after a test which I can't do now because my PC is on the fritz.